# is there any logged in field in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i am having fields like username , email , usertype in my backend table

As created and modified fields present in cakephp do there is any field present in codeigniter that will save time when user has last logged in to the system?

Comment: default logged_in field to track when was my user last logged in..........thanks in advance

Comment: i think no checked the doc, you can create your self acc. to your need.

Comment: i am new to codeigniter... so kind a help me... can this be possible with a query?

Answer (score 0):

Docs :
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database

For new start

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

For inserting in table

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use database with combination of CodeIgniter's session class to store your `session` data, so you can track user's last_activity. `Codeiginter` has option to store session data in database, you must first create a database table for this purpose.
Here is a sample table you can create for that

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Then in your `config.php` you should use

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Using this table you can save/update user's activity everytime the user logs in/out. For more [**read this documentation**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) (See in the "Saving Session Data to a Database").